# How to run aspnet_regiis command programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to run aspnet_regiis command problematically

I want this code to be run in C# code programmatically

**aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connection Strings" "C:\Users\99xccba\Desktop\connection string\DNN"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Simple task

Main method

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Method to run windows process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processName">Process Name</param>
    /// <param name="arguments">Arguments </param>
    private void RunProcess(string processName, string arguments)
    {
        var newProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(processName);
        Log("User: " + GetSystemName());

        if (arguments.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            newProcess.Arguments = arguments;
        newProcess.CreateNoWindow = false;
        newProcess.ErrorDialog = true;
        newProcess.RedirectStandardError = true;
        newProcess.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        newProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        newProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
        using (var proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo = newProcess;
            proc.Start();
            Log(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

Process of call this method

```
string framework = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe";

                if (8 == IntPtr.Size
                    || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
                    framework = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe";


                RunProcess(framework, "-ga " + GetSystemName());
```

Comment: This code suppose to run in windows command line..I need this to be run progmatically please help expert with steps of coding.. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC>aspnet_regiis
ectionStrings" "C:\Users\99xccba\Desktop\connection string\DNN"

Answer (score -1):

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "dir";
process.Start();
```

Make sure you have proper paths declared. Then replace Arguments with your own command. Or you could create a batch file with paths set up and execute that instead.

Comment: CMD not get started with c:/ but it start with the location from where that the running code exist..

Comment: Yes, that's why I said  you need to set paths correctly. I leave that to you.